# Easiest way to rename all columns to add index position

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame of 50 columns in it, and I want to rename each column to include the index position.

so columnA would be columnA_0, columnB would be columnB_1, and so on.

I could do manually for each line, like:

`df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[1]: str(df.columns[1]) + '_'+ str(dftest.index[1])})`

But I want to know if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set the names directly:

```
df.columns= [f"{col}_{ix}" for ix, col in enumerate(df.columns)]
```